# BirthDay calculated column on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, microsoft365

Ive been working on a list in sharepoint and i want to know if today there are birthdays. So i created a calculated column using a born date.

I can know if the actual month is equal to the born month and if the actual day is equal to the born day, but i cant know both. I dont know why.

These code sentences works for me:

```
=DAY(TODAY())=DAY([Fecha Nacimiento])
=MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH([Fecha Nacimiento])
```

i need something like this but it doesnt works:

```
=AND(DAY(TODAY())=DAY([Fecha Nacimiento]), MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH([Fecha Nacimiento]))
```

This is the error that i got:

> The security validation of this page has timed out. Click Back in your web browser, refresh the page, and try the operation again.

What's supposed that i have to do?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, your formula works on my end. I did not get the error like yours.

Besides, you could try to use `NOW()` instead of `TODAY()` , check if that works for you.

```
=AND(DAY(NOW())=DAY([Fecha Nacimiento]), MONTH(NOW())=MONTH([Fecha Nacimiento]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! It doesnt works for me yet. I got this error :

> The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.